# Postgres Go query gives error relation TABLE does not exist

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a Postgres table created with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts
(
accountid       VARCHAR(56)  PRIMARY KEY,
balance         BIGINT       NOT NULL CHECK (balance >= 0),
seqnum          BIGINT       NOT NULL,
numsubentries   INT          NOT NULL CHECK (numsubentries >= 0),
homedomain      VARCHAR(32)  NOT NULL,
thresholds      TEXT         NOT NULL,
lastmodified    INT          NOT NULL
);
```

I'm using Postgres as my sql driver and using Go's native sql library. My main function looks like this:

```
func main() {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    sqlStatement := "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accountid='123'"
    log.Println(sqlStatement)

    rows, err := db.Query(sqlStatement)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
}
```

When I run this, I get the error `relation "accounts" does not exist at character 15`. The panic happens at the last error checking, hence the `db.Query(sqlStatement)` line. However, when I run the same query on the command line, results return correctly.

I read that this error often means the table name is not spelled correctly. I double checked this and it doesn't seem to be the case. I also checked that the user credentials I'm using have access right to the `accounts` table. It does, so I'm hoping some have had experience with this.

Comment: You are probably connecting to a different database.

Comment: Your connected database might not have that table. Another possibility, the table might be created using an identifier like "Accounts" then it is not accounts but "Accounts". Maybe query your tables first.

Comment: You are right. I double check the user but the not database. I had created the schema under the wrong database. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I had created the table under the wrong database. I double checked the user but not the database name I'm connecting to.